# Keep salts when moving a site?

Tags: php

Should I keep the salts when moving a site to another server or should I create new ones and how do the passwords remain readable then?

Comment: By salts you mean the `AUTH_KEY`, `AUTH_SALT`, .. constants usually defined in wp-config.php?

Comment: Are you keeping the same domain name?

Comment: @kero, yes I mean `AUTH_KEY`, `AUTH_SALT`, etc... @Rup yes, I keep the same domain name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change them.

Its good practice to periodically change your wordpress salts.

It will not affect the passwords in the database but it will log out all users.

Comment: Thank you @Buttered_Toast, this answers my question!

Comment: @mrcodefinger As a source, it also [says so in the wp-config-sample.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.6.1/wp-config-sample.php#L45): "You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again."

Comment: @kero, Thanks for the advice, would not have come so quickly on the idea times to look into the wp-config-sample.php